# Setting up SSL with WCF on Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, x509certificate

I'm trying to set up a WCF-service with SSL on Azure.

Can someone please explain a bit about the differences of using certificates is these cases?

1. Certificate for https-binding in IIS
2. ServiceCertificate in Web.Config
3. ClientCertificate in Web.Config
4. Certificate in ServiceDefinition.csdef
5. Certificate in ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg
6. Certificate in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg
7. More I should know about?

I want to publish several service-endpoints within the same role, some with SSL and some without. Do I need binding-certificates at all or is it service-certificates I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading [WCF Transport Security with Certificate Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074.aspx) and [Configuring SSL for an application in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl/)

1. Certificate for https-binding in IIS - exactly what it says, the cert is used by IIS to create a secure binding on a site/service, typically on port 443
2. ServiceCertificate in Web.Config - WCF service-side binding cert used for WCF Transport Security with Certificate Authentication - private key cert used to authenticate client request signed with the corresponding public key
3. ClientCertificate in Web.Config - WCF client-side binding cert used for WCF Transport Security with Certificate Authentication - public key cert used to sign a request for authentication to a service using Transport Security with the corresponding private key
4. Certificate in ServiceDefinition.csdef - default certificate used to create a secure endpoint in Azure worker & web roles. NOTE: This is the certificate Azure installs in IIS to bind to the service endpoint (see #1)
5. Certificate in ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg - same as 4, just used in a "Local" build/deployment configuration
6. Certificate in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg - same as 4, just used in a "Cloud" build/deployment configuration